# Not able to consume Apache Kafka Messages NotCoordinatorForGroupError

Tags: apache-kafka

New to Kafka, have dpeloyed it on localhost, I am able to write to the Topics but unable to consume the messages.
When i check the offsets, I can see that there are messages.

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --replication-factor 1 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partitions 1 --topic Topic1
Created topic Topic1.
~/kafka/config$ echo "Hello, World" | ~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic Topic1 > /dev/null
~/kafka/config$ ../bin//kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic Topic1 --time -1
Topic1:0:1
~/kafka/config$ ../bin//kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic Topic1 --time -2
Topic1:0:0
~/kafka/config$ ~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic Topic1 --from-beginning

(blank)
```

Tried writing a Python script for the same: This is the repeating output:

```
DEBUG:kafka.coordinator:Sending group coordinator request for group test-grp-1 to broker 0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request GroupCoordinatorRequest_v0(consumer_group='test-grp-1')
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=0 host=localhost:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Request 5: GroupCoordinatorRequest_v0(consumer_group='test-grp-1')
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Received correlation id: 5
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Processing response GroupCoordinatorResponse_v0
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=0 host=localhost:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Response 5 (1.7061233520507812 ms): GroupCoordinatorResponse_v0(error_code=0, coordinator_id=0, host='localhost', port=9092)
DEBUG:kafka.coordinator:Received group coordinator response GroupCoordinatorResponse_v0(error_code=0, coordinator_id=0, host='localhost', port=9092)
DEBUG:kafka.cluster:Updating coordinator for test-grp-1: GroupCoordinatorResponse_v0(error_code=0, coordinator_id=0, host='localhost', port=9092)
INFO:kafka.cluster:Group coordinator for test-grp-1 is BrokerMetadata(nodeId='coordinator-0', host='localhost', port=9092, rack=None)
INFO:kafka.coordinator:Discovered coordinator coordinator-0 for group test-grp-1
INFO:kafka.coordinator:(Re-)joining group test-grp-1
DEBUG:kafka.coordinator:Sending JoinGroup (JoinGroupRequest_v2(group='test-grp-1', session_timeout=10000, rebalance_timeout=300000, member_id='', protocol_type='consumer', group_protocols=[(protocol_name='range', protocol_metadata=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06Topic1\x00\x00\x00\x00'), (protocol_name='roundrobin', protocol_metadata=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06Topic1\x00\x00\x00\x00')])) to coordinator coordinator-0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request JoinGroupRequest_v2(group='test-grp-1', session_timeout=10000, rebalance_timeout=300000, member_id='', protocol_type='consumer', group_protocols=[(protocol_name='range', protocol_metadata=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06Topic1\x00\x00\x00\x00'), (protocol_name='roundrobin', protocol_metadata=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06Topic1\x00\x00\x00\x00')])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=coordinator-0 host=localhost:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Request 6: JoinGroupRequest_v2(group='test-grp-1', session_timeout=10000, rebalance_timeout=300000, member_id='', protocol_type='consumer', group_protocols=[(protocol_name='range', protocol_metadata=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06Topic1\x00\x00\x00\x00'), (protocol_name='roundrobin', protocol_metadata=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06Topic1\x00\x00\x00\x00')])
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Received correlation id: 6
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Processing response JoinGroupResponse_v2
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=coordinator-0 host=localhost:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Response 6 (1.4925003051757812 ms): JoinGroupResponse_v2(throttle_time_ms=0, error_code=16, generation_id=-1, group_protocol='', leader_id='', member_id='', members=[])
WARNING:kafka.coordinator:Marking the coordinator dead (node coordinator-0) for group test-grp-1: [Error 16] NotCoordinatorForGroupError.
DEBUG:kafka.coordinator:Attempt to join group test-grp-1 failed due to obsolete coordinator information: NotCoordinatorForGroupError
```

Answer (score 0):

Below command will be useful for you to consume messages from topic partition.

./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic --partition 0